# c++ cannot convert argument 1 from "_Ty" to NeuralLayer*

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to make a neural network and am working on my feedforward algorithm. I'm passing in a pointer to the next layer as one of the arguments, but it doesn't seem to like it. Here is the for loop that is propagating the values forward through the network and the error below it:

```
for (int layer = 0; layer < this->Topology.Num(); layer++) {
        if (layer < this->Topology.Num() - 1) {
            //The line below is line 31
            neuralLayers.at(layer).FeedForward(this->neuralLayers.at(layer + 1));
        }
    }


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'void NeuralLayer::FeedForward(NeuralLayer *)': cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to 'NeuralLayer *' LeapNetUE4  F:\Doc_2\LeapNetUE4\Source\LeapNetUE4\Private\NeuralNetwork.cpp 31  
Error   C2676   binary '++': 'std::vector<Neuron,std::allocator<_Ty>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator    LeapNetUE4  F:\Doc_2\LeapNetUE4\Source\LeapNetUE4\Private\NeuralLayer.cpp   22
```

I'm new to c++ so I'm not entirely familiar with the errors shown. Line 31 refers to the feed forward function call. Line 22 refers to the second line on the code below in my NeuralLayer cpp file:

```
void NeuralLayer::FeedForward(NeuralLayer* nextLayer) {
    for (int neuron = 0; neuron < this->neurons.size(); neuron++
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show where these errors occurred. Mark the two lines with comments so that it’s clear.

Comment: @PeteBecker Sorting that out now. Give me a few minutes

Comment: @PeteBecker Added in the extra detail as it was across 2 cpp files

Comment: It looks to me like `neuralLayers` is a `std::vector<Neuron>`, and you are trying to pass a single `Neuron` *object* where a `NeuralLayer*` *pointer* is expected, which will not work.  If `Neuron` derives from `NeuralLayer`, then try using the `&` address operator to get a `Neuron*` pointer, which will then be implictly convertible to `NeuralLayer*`, eg: `neuralLayers.at(layer).FeedForward(&(neuralLayers.at(layer + 1)));`

Comment: @RemyLebeau `neuralLayers` is a `std::vector<NeuralLayer>`

Comment: @FallingInForward not accordingly to the error message you showed. But even in the case of `std::vector<NeuralLayer>`, you would still be passing a `NeuralLayer` *object* to a `NeuralLayer*` *pointer*.  So you would still need the `&` operator.  But why are you mixing objects and pointers like this? What does `FeedForward()` do with `nextLayer`, and why can't it take `nextLayer` as a `NeuralLayer&` reference instead of a `NeuralLayer*` pointer?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm still quite new to c++ so I'm too sure about when to use either ones. I think I know what each are, with * with a pointer and & being a reference but I thought functionally there are similar. Feedforward needs a reference or pointer so it can change the values within the next layer and I thought this way would be best though I could be wrong
The & worked, thank you

Comment: @FallingInForward rule of thumb - if a function parameter is not allowed to be null, then pass it by value or reference only. Pass by pointer only if a null is allowed.